# What is considered to be offline in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

At what point does Clash of Clans determine that the player is offline?

eg on my iPhone 5s, I can have the app still running in the background while I use a different app.  Is that considered to be offline?

Or I could leave the app open and let it idle, is it considered to be offline when it shows the "you  have been idle" message?

Answer (score 5):

You are determined offline when:

- The app is closed.
- The app is left inactive for 5 minutes.
- You are multitasking with Clash of Clans open in the background.

You are considered offline while the app is running in the background. You are also considered offline when you get the idle message:

[image: Idle Message]

Answer (score 4):

At any time you leave the app you are considered offline. There is also a session time-out after a certain timeframe of inactivity, whether you have the app open or not.

Comment: He asked multiple different questions in his question. Which one does your "yes" refer to? Can you provide more details?